# How to get app to refresh upon click if pages are within it in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, page-refresh

I have an app that is basically a navbar with a few links to other pages that display right underneath it. A few of the pages pull info from the database, or in this case, have a function to delete information from the database. The buttons work and do delete the info, but in order to refresh the data displayed on the page, I have to switch to another page on the navbar and then go back to the page I wish to update.

**AdminApp.js** (shortened for readability)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Row, Container, Col, Form,
} from 'reactstrap';
import AdminDashboard from './AdminDashboard';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ViewStudents from './ViewStudents';
import withAuth from './withAuth'; 


class AdminApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dropdownOpen: false
    }    
  }  

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Router>
          <Form>
            <div>
              <nav  className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li><Link to={'/viewstudents'}>View Students</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/viewgroups'}>Groups</Link></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
            <hr />
          <Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={AdminDashboard} />
              <Route path='/viewstudents' component={ViewStudents} />
              <Route path='/viewgroups' component={ViewGroups} />
          </Switch>     
            </div>
          </Form>
        </Router>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default withAuth(AdminApp);
```

If I want to use the "handleSubmit()" function in the code below, which works properly to delete users from the database, I press the delete button and it deletes them, but the page doesn't update until I switch to another page (let's say viewgroups) and then go back to it, which then displays the table without the students that were deleted.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Row,
  Container,
  Col,
  Form,
  FormGroup,
  Label,
  Input,
  Button,
  FormText,
  FormFeedback,
  CustomInput
} from "reactstrap";


class ViewStudents extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      students: [],
      year: year,
      term: term,
      IDs: [],
      checked: false
    }
    //this.fetch = this.fetch.bind(this)
    //this.getStudents = this.getStudents.bind(this)
    this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://10.171.204.211/GetStudents/", {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        year: this.state.year,
        term: this.state.term
      })
    })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      this.setState({
        students: data.map(item => ({
          firstName: item.fields.firstName,
          lastName: item.fields.lastName,
          UCFID: item.fields.UCFID,
          term: item.fields.term,
          year: item.fields.year,
          id: item.fields.authID,
        }))
      })

      console.log(this.state);
      console.log(this.state.students);
    })
    .catch( err => {
        console.log(err)
      })

  }

  handleDelete = event => {
    var arr = this.state.IDs
    arr.push(event.target.value)        
    this.setState({
      IDs: arr
  })
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    console.log(this.state);

    fetch("http://10.171.204.211/DeleteStudent/", { ///////// change 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })

    this.props.history.go('/AdminApp');
  }

  renderTableData() {
    //this.getStudents(this.state.year, this.state.term);
    return this.state.students.map((student, index) => {
       const { firstName, lastName, UCFID, term, year, id } = student //destructuring
       return (
          <tr>
             <td>{firstName}</td>
             <td>{lastName}</td>
             <td>{UCFID}</td>
             <td>{term}</td>
             <td>{year}</td>
             <td><label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name={id} value={id} 
                    onChange={this.handleDelete.bind(this)} />
                </label></td>
          </tr>
       )
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Form className="SDForm">
          <Col  className="SDForm">
            <h1 className="mainTitles">View Students</h1>
          </Col>
          <div>
          <table id='projects'>
               <tbody>
               <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>UCFID</th>
                <th>Term</th>
                <th>Year</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
               </tr>
               {this.renderTableData()}
               </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          <Button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Delete</Button>
        </Form> 
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default ViewStudents;
```

How could I make it automatically reload the page upon pressing the delete button? I've tried using this.props.history.push('/viewstudents') but it doesn't work since the page is displayed within the AdminApp page. I'm pretty new to react so I haven't been able to figure out much.

Comment: You don't need to reload the page, you need to "reload" set state with the latest info. Call the fetch do the data you want when clicking delete and set the state again.

Comment: @Train but how would I re-render the table? currently it is automatically rendered when the page opens

Comment: When you use state in the view, and you update the state using `this.setState({...})` after you delete. It re-renders the table automagically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table will re-render if you re-fetch the data **after** you delete. You could encapsulate the data-fetching logic into its own function for re-usability. It might look something like this:

```
getData= () => {
  // fetch your data and set your state as you were doing
  fetch("yourUrl").then(() => {//set your state});
}

componentDidMount(){
  this.getdata();
}

 handleSubmit = () => {
    console.log(this.state);

    fetch("http://10.171.204.211/DeleteStudent/", { ///////// change 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
    })
    .then(() => {
       // set your state with the new data
       this.getData();
     })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use state in the view, and you update the state using this.setState({...}) after you delete. React re-renders the table automagically.

in your `handleDelete` function do this

```
  handleDelete = event => {
    var arr = this.state.IDs
    arr.push(event.target.value)        
    this.setState({
      IDs: arr
  })
   this.setState({students:...}) //set the new data, either update the students array with a new one or fetch the data and update the state again
  }
```